# Avoid NotifyPropertyChanged in second collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have one observable collection of a class `BaseClass`(`ObservableCollection1<BaseClass>`) which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the properties Raise the event when something changes. I want to store my default values that I get on my call to database in another observable collection(`ObservableCollection2<BaseClass>`). My view is bound to `ObervableCollection1` and not 2 but if something changes in `BaseClass`, the values are updated in both 1 and 2 because of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `BaseClass`, How can I avoid the second `ObservableCollection2<BaseClass>` from being updated with the new values?

Comment: Either don't extend your `BaseClass` for the second collection... or just use a `List`... why does it have to be an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Or use Mode=OneTime on the ItemsSource binding.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can do as Scroog1 suggested or you might have to do a deep copy of the collection instead of a shallow copy...that is, clone all the elements in the collection so they are different instances of BaseClass.

Comment: Er, re-reading your slightly confusingly worded question, I get the impression that you misunderstand the problem you are having and Scroog1's suggestion won't work. The values will be updated in 2 regardless of INotifyPropertyChanged because the objects in both are the same instance. You have to do a deep copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deep copy is the key, all you have to do is to make your BaseClass implements ICloneable interface then add all the logic needed to copy your object. you can deep copy objects using binary serialization.

So first of all, your class MUST be marked as [Serializable] in order for this to work.

```
[Serializable]
    public class BaseClass: ICloneable
    {
        /*
        Base Class Mumbers ...
        */

        public object Clone()
        {
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (Stream str = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bf.Serialize(str, this);
                str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return bf.Deserialize(str);
            }
        }
    }
```

and finaly copy your source collection

```
var copiedCollection = new ObservableCollection<BaseClass>(sourceCollection.Select(a => (BaseClass)a.Clone()));
```

Comment: Thanks ..Works beautifully :)